# Что определяет 2-й параметр у b2World world()?

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, начал разбираться с box2d, версия у меня новая, 2.2.1. В сети ничего не нашел, кроме `b2World world(gravity, doSleep)` и т.п. Здесь мир принимает вектор гравитации и разрешение "спать объектам". А у меня эти параметры отсутствуют. Студия пишет, что второй параметр в b2World `world()` - это `const b2World &`. Что это? Мы ему передаем себя?
Объясните, пожалуйста...

Comment: Это ссылка на константный объект(экземпляр) типа(класса) b2World. Видимо b2World очень громоздкий класс, чтобы как-то быстро передать его внутрь метода можно использовать ссылки или указатели. В данном случае применяются ссылки.

Comment: Не, то что ссылка я понял, а вот для чего это сделано? Создают мир в мире???? Зачем что-то типа мир передавать в мир???

Comment: Сделано только для удобства вызова?

Comment: Например чтобы сделать копию, получить второй мир.

Comment: Ну чтож, спасибо, не знал что можно создавать несколько миров

Comment: Еще может быть вариант что класс мира - это синглтон Майерса и это просто особенность реализации паттерна.

private:        
        OnlyOne(){};
        OnlyOne(const OnlyOne& root);